# I have free time for Android development. I'd like suggestions on how to tackle this effectively

Tags: java, learning, android, skills, free-time

I'm finishing college for good tomorrow, then leaving my current programming job the next day. I'll be looking for opportunities, but I may end up with a month or two without a job, so with lots of free time to work on my Android development skills and improve my value for those jobs.

I started thinking about what I'll be doing to make the most out of all this time, and figured I'd need a good plan. I haven't coded too much in Java, but feel like I can grasp the syntax quite quickly. I have already played with ADT and the whole Android setup a bit, but never completed an app due to lack of time.

I'm looking for tips in order to finish the next month with the best skillset I can get in that time. Where to start with, tutorials, what to learn first, and so on. By the way, I do have an android device, so the emulator slowness or learning curve won't be an issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First things you need to understand are the application components and the lifecycle. See [Android Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) .

Then, follow the [NotePad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html), it will teach you especially how to use an SQLite DB, how to handle the application lifecycle and how to deal with lists.

Then, write something that uses `ListView` as they are used in many applications. For instance, write a demo that uses a custom `BaseAdapter` to show a list of people picture on the left with their names on the right. First store all the data locally and retrieve using what you learned after reading the [resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html) documentation. Then consider writing a web service client to retrieve the infos so you will familiarize with HTTP related classes.

You should easily do this in two weeks. In the remaining two weeks think about a small project and learn on the go.

Don't forget to check the [sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample).